# I have 2 .ear file inside a single domain (abc.ear and def.ear). How can I communicate between them

Tags: java

I have 2 .ear file under a single domain (eg : abc.ear, def.ear). How to communicate between them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Remote Method Invocation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Method_Invocation). Usually the beans of your application will be registered in the application server upon deployment. With the correct name you can then use a lookup to get that remote bean (remote meaning a bean from the other .ear). From there on you an use that bean as if it was a local one.

I am sure you can find a good tutorial on RMI for your specific application server.

**EDIT**: I just noticed that *communicate* is a rather broad term and my interpretation might not fit what you want. RMI is used to call methods and objects. If *communicate* means to transfer data only you could also use a middleware like [Java Message Service](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) to send messages to the other .ear.